# Sharepoint Farm - Adding in test servers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm

I'm currently planning a new SP farm that pretty much works as follows.

2 x WFE servers
3 x Application Servers
2 x SQL servers (Cluster 1 for SP databases and such)
2 x SQL servers (Cluster 2 for Search DB's)

Now I'd like to add some test servers in that I can develop on without affecting the live site. Can anyone recommend a suitable setup for instance would I add a specific server for DBs or use one of the existing clusters?

Regards,

PipBoy

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you set up both your development and test environment to be completely seperate from the production. If possible also with a seperate AD (or at least with a completely different set of accounts).

You've done a lot of investment into getting a redundant stable production environment, don't make a setup where a typo/wrong selection causes a service account to be locked or worse a production database to be deleted.

The test environment should look as much as production as possible, can be virtualized as you prabably isn't putting the same load on it.

The dev environment can be all on a single server or better have SQL on a seperate server which can be shared between multiple developers.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of this route but would need to devise a cloning policy for issues.